Trying to run script in debugging mode but getting "AssertionError: group argument must be None for now"
I have a problem related to this question:
"Threading: AssertionError: group argument must be None for now"
In normal run mode, everything works,
but you can't run it in debug mode.
Even such a code:
HW = ("Hello", "World", "!")

for w in HW:
    print(w)

leads to such an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):-cdbd-433c-9122-a320e814869b
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 268, in run_file
    start_debugging(target)
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 258, in start_debugging
    debugpy.connect(options.address, access_token=options.adapter_access_token)
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\public_api.py", line 31, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 143, in debug
    log.reraise_exception("{0}() failed:", func.__name__, level="info")
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 141, in debug
    return func(address, settrace_kwargs, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 297, in connect
    _settrace(host=host, port=port, client_access_token=access_token, **settrace_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 45, in _settrace
    return pydevd.settrace(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 2821, in settrace
    _locked_settrace(
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 2944, in _locked_settrace
    py_db.enable_tracing(py_db.trace_dispatch, apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1107, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.SetTrace(thread_trace_func)
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_tracing.py", line 87, in SetTrace
    if set_trace_to_threads(tracing_func, thread_idents=[thread.get_ident()], create_dummy_thread=False) == 0:        
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Stas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_tracing.py", line 354, in set_trace_to_threads
    start_new_thread(increase_tracing_count, ())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 905, in __init__
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?
I don't understand what changed and at what point,
but I can't run python scripts in debug mode.
I reinstalled the interpreter, but it didn't help.

OneСricket, you added the tag: "visual-studio-code", maybe you know what the problem is or how it can be fixed? Let's solve this problem!

I haven't figured out why this problem occurred,
but thanks to a tip from OneCricketeer, I fixed the situation.
Most lines of the error text pointed to a folder with the extension "Python Debugger".
I reinstalled this extension, which fixed the situation.

I just edited to clarify this answer, but I'm not sure why you said "helped to fix the situation", which implies you had to do something else too. I assume you meant that it itself fixed the situation, but correct me if I'm wrong :)

And for "deleted" I assume you meant "uninstalled", but again correct me if I'm wrong, like if you actually deleted the extension files off your computer.

wjandrea, thanks for editing my answer, I used machine translation, perhaps that's why the text of the answer was not completely clear.
The problem was solved by reinstalling the VS Code extension "Python Debugger".
